# Why is it easier to compare two functions of the same variable by looking at the graphs of the reciprocals?

Tags: statistics, functions

[image]

The above snapshot is from my lecture notes. We have the two functions of the same variable. To compare them they suggest looking at the graphs of the reciprocals of the functions. I don't understand how that, in any way, helps compare more easily? How it even relates at all?

Comment: its just that it will be easier that way ..you can also compare the functions by directly  drawing graph of the functions.

Comment: @AbhashJha why is it easier that way?

Comment: You can then have a standard log(f(c)) function rather than $\frac{k}{log(f(c))}$ and see the reciprocals of the functions have same point of intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are comparing as $\alpha$ tends to $0$? If so, then it's hard to graphically compare behavior of two functions as they shoot off to infinity since it's impossible to directly visualize the comparison of two near-infinite slopes (with a nearly-infinite slope, every small change in $\alpha$ corresponds to a huge change in range value, say $y$; something very hard to capture and compare meaningfully by drawing a graph). However, looking at the reciprocals instead gives you a way to compare which removes the tend to infinity. Moreover, notice that 
$$
\frac{E(\alpha)}{R(\alpha)} = \frac{S(\alpha)}{F(\alpha)},$$ 
and hence you can capture certain relative analytic behaviors by looking at the reciprocals.

Comment: It doesn't specifically state that Alpha tends to Zero but I'm going to assume that too since it only makes sense now that way. Cheers Tom.